# VS8 can't handle file.close(); file.open();, why?

Tags: c++

I've got, probably trivial question but i can't understand it.
I've wrote the simple code:

```
fstream file;
file.open("data", ios::in);
if(!file.good()){
   file.close();
   file.open("data", ios::out);
   if(!file.good()) cout<<"not good"<<endl;
   file<<"test"<<endl;
   file.close();
}
```

in fresh VS8 C++ Express project. When I run it and "data" doesn't exists, it creates file, but also returns "not good"(the second one) so the output is not written in file. And now comes the funny thing. If I compile same code in VS10 C++ Express and Code::Blocks 12, it works fine.

Why is it so?

@edit
My friend checked it on his PC with VS8 C++ Expres too. Works same for him.

@edit2 Same as my comment with "solution":

> Forcing to clear failbit with .clear(); method seems to work. It hurts
>   when you learn in newer IDE and then has to switch to older one :/.
>   Tho, it gives nice lesson. Thanks guys.

Comment: Different compilers sometimes have different implementations of the standard. Especially Microsoft compilers...

Comment: You can use `is_open` instead of `good`.

Comment: Perhaps the failbit is not being cleared after the first failure. It looks like "open" now clears the failbit on success in C++11 and perhaps this change was made in VS2010 in anticipation of some of the new standard features (click on the tabs that show differences between C++03 and C++11 http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/open/)

Comment: Just a tip. When you encounter something like this refer to the C++ Standard to see which behavior is expected. It many cases certain behavior is left up to the implementation which means it can change and cannot be relied upon to be the same between different versions of the library.

Comment: A little idea/detail: I'm not one hundred percent sure, but I believe error state flags are set only after read/write operations, so it could also be that their state right after the opening of a file is not mandated by the standard.

Comment: try single-stepping the library code, you may spot the reason why good() is false. In any case I'd suggest clear() after any hard discovery of failure -- possibly it would cure the problem for good, and can't hurt.

Comment: Forcing to clear failbit with .clear(); method seems to work. It hurts when you learn in newer IDE and then has to switch to older one :/. Tho, it gives nice lesson.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was by design.  In C++98, closing an fstream does not clear the error state and calling `open()` on an fstream does not reset the error state.  See [LWG Defect #409](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#409) for a discussion of the issue.

The behavior was changed in C++11 such that the error state is cleared (via a call to `clear()`) if the open operation succeeds.

Comment: Is there anywhere that Microsoft shares this information apart from through its developers who happen to be perusing StackOverflow questions? I tried searching for this information briefly about the behavior of fstream::open in VS2010 relative to VS2008, but could not quickly find anything worthwhile.

Comment: @statueuphemism:  The documentation on MSDN is the authoritative documentation for the implementation.  The [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/) website is also very good (for the C++ Standard Library, it is our intent to implement the libraries as specified; we take conformance very seriously).

Comment: Here is the MSDN article for fstream open in VS2010 (traced back to basic_fstream::open) which makes no mention of the behavior you describe as an update to comply with C++0x (only drafts of C++11 were available for VS2010's release): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4dx08bh4(v=vs.100).aspx As a developer who is looking to potentially migrate to a later version of Visual Studio, release notes to document these changes would be very helpful to prevent subtle bugs due to undocumented behavior changes. I also browsed http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465215(v=vs.100).aspx